# Navigate page in Spotfire by clicking on a Javascript element in JS Viz?

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire, datatables-1.10

I have created a JS Viz in Spotfire using Datatables.js
I want to navigate to another page, by clicking on a number in the table (each column corresponds to a specific page/tab in spotfire)

I know that navigation can be done by triggering a script , but thats usually bound to an action item having a "spotfire id"(uniquely generated).

I'm totally lost on how I can achieve this, can anyone give me a direction to work on?

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem, contact me for the solution

Comment: Hey, it's great you found a solution! Would you please share?

Comment: If you post a question here and you expect someone to answer your question, why would you hold the answer back?

Comment: @jleviaguirre Sorry for that

My flow was

***Click on cell --> set Document property to value based on the column --> Trigger an Iron python script based on change of Document Property value -->Iron python script navigates it to the page i want , with the help of a bunch of if else statements based on the value set in the document property.***

I might have the code somewhere ,would need some time getting it. But the trick is setting the document property from JS Viz. 
which you can do with the help of

Comment: `var DocumentPropertyInfo = { "PropertyName": name, "PropertyValue": value };
Spotfire.Modify ( "documentproperty", DocumentPropertyInfo );`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript approach
html

```
<span id="startButton" style="cursor:default">[Start]</span>
<span id="stopButton" style="cursor:pointer">[Stop]</span>
```

JavaScript

```
//parameters
var pages = [0, 1, 3];   //◄ Select the pages you want to cycle through. 0 is the first one
var timeout = 10000;      //◄ Select the time in ms to delay between pages. 10000 is 10 seconds

//maintain a registry of interval in case multiple are triggered to stop them all at once with the stop button

window["intervalIds"]??=[];
tmp=[...pages]

function startCycle() {
    (function cycle(){
        page = tmp.shift();
        if(!tmp.length) tmp=[...pages]
        goToPage(page);
        window.intervalIds.push(setTimeout(cycle, timeout));
    })();
}



function stopCycle() {
      console.log("Slideshow Ended")
      window.intervalIds.forEach(clearInterval);
}



function goToPage(x) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sf-element-page-tab")[x].click();
}



// Hook html buttons to start and stop functions
document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = startCycle;
document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick = stopCycle;
```